# How to auto-start IBM WebSphere application server 9.x

Tags: websphere, websphere-9

I have

1. Dmgro1
2. Application Server profile (federated with Dmgr01)
3. No cluster configuration

I have added Dmgr01 and Node agent as windows services and they start automatically. Now, I want the application server associated with the node agent to start automatically. I tried selecting the option "Start Components as needed" but no luck. Can someone help me on how to start the application server automatically when node agent starts

[image: WebSphere admin console]

Comment: You should deselect start components as needed. It affects how the server starts, not when. Have you considered registering the server as a Windows service?

Comment: I tried but when I used  wasservicehelper.bat to register Dmgr01 and application server profile (ex: Custom01), got a warning message like                                                     
"Hint: If the application server is running in an ND environment
then only the nodeagent and deployment manager servers should be
started as a Windows service.

Warning: In an ND environment, starting the application server as
a service may fail under certain conditions where its nodeagent is running." so I did not register the server under windows service

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please take a look at this link:
How nodeagent monitors WebSphere Application Server
https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/how-nodeagent-monitors-websphere-application-server

You should not set the appserver that is federated to a dmgr to start with a Windows Service, you should use the nodeagents ability to start the servers, which is controlled by each application servers monitoring policy